# iPad create PDF with loading animation

Tags: ipad, pdf

i´m using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData to create PDF Files with Multiple Pages. Everything is working fine... My problem is that when the App creates a bigger amount of pages, for 1 PDF, its freezing for a short time and i have no control over the UI. The PDF File is created correctly, but i want to show a loading screen or something like that. Everything i tested like a UIAlertView within an UIActivityIndicator or just an UIActivityIndicator in the Toolbar are showing AFTER the PDF is done.

Here my method for creating the NSData Object. The NSLog shows the correct output:
I really have no idea how to show the progress of creating the PDF. A simple UILabel which shows the current page would be just what i need.

```
- (NSData *)createPDFData:(int)type {

    NSLog(@"START");

    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, drawImage.bounds, nil);

    if (type == 1) {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        if ([self loadPDFBackground]) [paperImage drawRect:paperImage.bounds];
        [drawImage drawRect:drawImage.bounds];
    } else if (type == 2) {
        NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self loadImagesForPDF]];
        int imageCount = [images count];
        for (int i=0; i<imageCount; i++) {

            NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %i of %i", i+1, imageCount]);

            drawImage.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            if ([self loadPDFBackground]) [paperImage drawRect:paperImage.bounds];
            [drawImage drawRect:drawImage.bounds];
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    NSLog(@"END");

    return pdfData;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are creating the PDF file on the main/UI thread and causes the application to freeze if the PDF file is very large. Since you are blocking the UI thread, no activity indicators can run and display progress. The solution is to run the PDF creation method on a separate thread and when the job is done, send a notification to the UI. In this way you can have the activity indicators and you dismiss them when you receive the notification from the PDF creation thread.